# nmcli device wifi list only sees open networks

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, nmcli

Running a scan with

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

is only showing me entries for routers that do not use any WEP/WPA encryption.  I can see about 30 different routers from my phone's wifi scan.  The only one that shows through `nmcli` has no WEP/WPA security.  Is there any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Do you see more access points if you run `nmcli dev wifi rescan` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out... I've now discovered almost a year later that the device I was running nmcli dev wifi on had a broken wifi antenna.  Once I replaced the antenna, everything functioned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, if you are already connected to a router via ethernet when you do the wifi scan, the scan will only return the SSID of the router you are connected to via ethernet.  It ignores all other SSIDs.

Interestingly, I used a second router as a bridge to a primary router.  When connected to the second router via ethernet, nmcli dev wifi list returned the SSID of both the primary router and the bridging router.